# discord.py - when i try to change username i get such an error does anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: python, discord.py

This error appears after starting the program:

await client.edit_profile(password=discordpass, username=Name)
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'edit_profile'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this Github comment](https://gist.github.com/MrLotU/b11d868243062ba9210f4994c1158d43#gistcomment-3074185), you have to do:

```py
await client.user.edit(password=discordpass, username=Name)
```